# Generate repeated byte chunks for padding binaries

Tags: elixir

We have the binary `<<"stackoverflow">>` and want to apply pkcs7 padding (as known format example) to fill it out to 16 bytes. Eg. We want 3 bytes of the integer 3 padded onto the end: `<<"stackoverflow", 3, 3, 3>>`

Answer (score 4):

*Erlang* has a built in function called `:binary.copy(binary, count)` which is probably the fasted function. You can call it as so from Elixir:

```
<<"stackoverflow">> <> :binary.copy(<<3>>, 3)
```

As least up to 1.15 (current at time of writing), `String.duplicate` is an alias to `:binary.copy` so you may use `String.duplicate` if desired. "Strings" do have a specific meaning in Elixir and not all strings are binaries. You *may* fall into trouble later if the underlying implementation changes, for example if `String.duplicate(subject, n)` starts checking the given `subject` is a *valid* string instead of just any sequence of bytes.

If you're padding with zeros, you can use the regular binary construction syntax (`<<0::unsigned-size(count * 8 [bits])>>`), which is faster. You can fiddle with the endianness to place your number at one end of the padding.

Additionally, you can generate the number that matches the desired byte sequence
(see "bitshift" in the benchmark) but this probably has limited application compared to all zero or `:binary.copy`.

With the naive benchmark:

```
count = 500

Benchee.run(%{
  "binary.copy" => fn ->
    <<"stackoverflow">> <> :binary.copy(<<3>>, count)
  end,
  "for" => fn ->
    <<"stackoverflow">> <> for _ <- 1..count, into: <<>>, do: <<3>>
  end,
  "Enum.into" => fn ->
    <<"stackoverflow">> <> Enum.into(1..count, <<>>, fn _ -> <<3>> end)
  end,
  "iodata" => fn ->
    [<<"stackoverflow">>, Enum.map(1..count, fn _ -> 3 end)]
    |> IO.iodata_to_binary()
  end,
  "<<0::unsigned>>" => fn ->
    # note this cannot generate /repeated/ bytes, but can fill the first or last if you
    # set the endianness.
    <<"stackoverflow"::binary, 0::unsigned-size(count * 8)>>
  end,
  "bitshift <<n::unsigned>>" => fn ->
    # note Enum.reduce is probably slightly slower than a recursive module.def(count, n) function
    n = Enum.reduce(1..count, 3, fn _, sum -> Bitwise.<<<(sum, 8) + 3 end)
    <<"stackoverflow"::binary, n::unsigned-size(count * 8)>>
  end
})
```

We get

```
Name                               ips        average  deviation         median         99th %
<<0::unsigned>>               537.62 K        1.86 μs  ±1077.40%        1.24 μs        3.64 μs
binary.copy                   233.90 K        4.28 μs   ±682.75%        3.13 μs        9.52 μs
iodata                         22.68 K       44.10 μs    ±21.13%       42.05 μs       89.54 μs
bitshift <<n::unsigned>>        3.27 K      306.03 μs     ±8.04%      302.19 μs      368.46 μs
Enum.into                       2.49 K      401.43 μs    ±36.27%      362.18 μs     1015.46 μs
for                             0.74 K     1357.00 μs     ±9.86%     1330.88 μs     1746.24 μs

Comparison: 
<<0::unsigned>>               537.62 K
binary.copy                   233.90 K - 2.30x slower +2.42 μs
iodata                         22.68 K - 23.71x slower +42.24 μs
bitshift <<n::unsigned>>        3.27 K - 164.52x slower +304.17 μs
Enum.into                       2.49 K - 215.81x slower +399.57 μs
for                             0.74 K - 729.54x slower +1355.14 μs
```

Comment: Nice benchmark. I tried recursion too, but it was still about 5 times slower than `:binary.copy`.

Answer (score 0):

As a function:

```elixir
defmodule Padder do
  def pad_bytes(binary, size, byte \\ 0)
  def pad_bytes(binary, size, _byte) when byte_size(binary) >= size, do: binary

  def pad_bytes(binary, size, byte) do
    binary <> :binary.copy(<<byte>>, size - byte_size(binary))
  end
end
```

Usage:

```elixir
iex> Padder.pad_bytes("stackoverflow", 16)
<<115, 116, 97, 99, 107, 111, 118, 101, 114, 102, 108, 111, 119, 0, 0, 0>>
iex> Padder.pad_bytes("stackoverflow", 16, 3)
<<115, 116, 97, 99, 107, 111, 118, 101, 114, 102, 108, 111, 119, 3, 3, 3>>
```